# Adding avr-gcc to a Yocto SDK

Tags: gcc, yocto, avr, avr-gcc

I am attempting to put `avr-gcc` into the sdk of my Yocto (Zeus) image. I have the following recipe for `avr-gcc`.

```
SUMMARY = "GNU compiler for Microchip (formerly Atmel) AVR microcontrollers"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/"
SECTION = "devel"
LICENSE = "GPLv2+"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "\
    file://COPYING;md5=59530bdf33659b29e73d4adb9f9f6552 \
    file://COPYING3;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504 \
    file://COPYING3.LIB;md5=6a6a8e020838b23406c81b19c1d46df6 \
    file://COPYING.LIB;md5=2d5025d4aa3495befef8f17206a5b0a1 \
    file://COPYING.RUNTIME;md5=fe60d87048567d4fe8c8a0ed2448bcc8 \
"

inherit autotools gettext texinfo

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"

DEPENDS = " \
    avr-binutils \
    zlib \
    gawk \
    gmp \
    mpfr \
    libmpc \
    flex \
"
DEPENDS_append_class-target = " ${BPN}-native"

PE = "1"

SRC_URI = "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-${PV}/gcc-${PV}.tar.xz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "bb815a8e3b7be43c4a26fa89dbbd9795"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "e30a6e52d10e1f27ed55104ad233c30bd1e99cfb5ff98ab022dc941edd1b2dd4"

S = "${WORKDIR}/gcc-${PV}"

EXTRA_OECONF = " \
    --target=avr \
    --program-prefix=avr- \
    --enable-languages=c,c++ \
    --enable-c99 \
    --enable-long-long \
    --disable-bootstrap \
    --disable-libmudflap \
    --with-system-zlib \
    --with-build-sysroot=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET} \
"

EXTRA_OECONF_append_class-target = " \
    --with-gnu-as \
    --with-gnu-ld \
    --with-as=${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/avr-as \
    --with-ld=${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/avr-ld \
"

export AR_FOR_TARGET = "avr-ar"
export AS_FOR_TARGET = "avr-as"
export DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET = "avr-dlltool"
export CC_FOR_TARGET = "avr-gcc"
export CXX_FOR_TARGET = "avr-g++"
export GCC_FOR_TARGET = "avr-gcc"
export LD_FOR_TARGET = "avr-ld"
export LIPO_FOR_TARGET = "avr-lipo"
export NM_FOR_TARGET = "avr-nm"
export OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET = "avr-objdump"
export RANLIB_FOR_TARGET = "avr-ranlib"
export STRIP_FOR_TARGET = "avr-strip"
export WINDRES_FOR_TARGET = "avr-windres"

do_configure_preend_class-target() {
    # broken libtool here - stolen from oe-core gcc-source.inc
    #sed -i -e 's/hardcode_into_libs=yes/hardcode_into_libs=no/' ${S}/libcc1/configure
}

do_configure() {
        (cd ${S} && gnu-configize)

        oe_runconf
}

do_install_append() {
    # fix some host contamination - TBD: fix properly
    for file in `find ${D}/${libdir}/gcc/avr/${PV}/include`; do
        chown root:root $file
    done
    for file in `find ${D}/${libdir}/gcc/avr/${PV}/include-fixed`; do
        chown root:root $file
    done

    # remove some files conflicting with target utils
    rm -rf ${D}/${datadir}/locale
    rm -rf ${D}/${datadir}/info
    rm -rf ${D}/${datadir}/man/man7
}

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/gcc/avr"

FILES_${PN}-staticdev += " \
    ${libdir}/gcc/avr/${PV}/*.a \
    ${libdir}/gcc/avr/${PV}/*/*.a \
    ${libdir}/gcc/avr/${PV}/*/*/*.a \
"

# as long as there is no other libc we can pin avr-libc
RDEPENDS_${PN}_class-target += " \
    ${PN}-staticdev \
    avr-libc \
"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-so"
```

When I run `bitbake nativesdk-avr-gcc` I get a compile error:

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fmacro-prefix-map...
```

The `-native` variant compiles just fine, though it's CFLAGS does not contain `-fmacro-prefix-map`

---

On a somewhat related sidenote, I did the same with the following `avr-binutils` recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "GNU binutils for Microchip (formerly Atmel) AVR microcontrollers"
LICENSE = "GPLv2+"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM="\
    file://COPYING;md5=59530bdf33659b29e73d4adb9f9f6552\
    file://COPYING.LIB;md5=9f604d8a4f8e74f4f5140845a21b6674\
    file://COPYING3;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504\
    file://COPYING3.LIB;md5=6a6a8e020838b23406c81b19c1d46df6\
    file://gas/COPYING;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504\
    file://include/COPYING;md5=59530bdf33659b29e73d4adb9f9f6552\
    file://include/COPYING3;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504\
    file://libiberty/COPYING.LIB;md5=a916467b91076e631dd8edb7424769c7\
    file://bfd/COPYING;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504\
"

inherit autotools gettext texinfo

SRC_URI = " \
    ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/binutils/binutils-${PV}.tar.xz \
    file://avr-size.patch \
"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "664ec3a2df7805ed3464639aaae332d6"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "f00b0e8803dc9bab1e2165bd568528135be734df3fabf8d0161828cd56028952"

S = "${WORKDIR}/binutils-${PV}"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"

EXTRA_OECONF = "--target=avr"

do_configure () {
        (cd ${S} && gnu-configize)

        oe_runconf
    #
    # must prime config.cache to ensure the build of libiberty
    #
        mkdir -p ${B}/build-${BUILD_SYS}
        for i in ${CONFIG_SITE}; do
                cat $i >> ${B}/build-${BUILD_SYS}/config.cache || true
        done
}

do_install_append() {
    # remove some files conflicting with target utils
    rm -rf ${D}/${datadir}/locale
    rm -rf ${D}/${datadir}/info
}

FILES_${PN} += "${prefix}/avr"
SYSROOT_DIRS_append_class-native = " ${prefix}/avr"
```

When I `bitbake nativesdk-avr-binutils`, it compiles just fine. The CFLAGS within when building this recipe does include `-fmacro-prefix-map` and it appears to be using the same compiler as `nativesdk-avr-gcc` when it builds.

Is there something specific to `avr-gcc` which is incorrect?

---

For reference I am building off [meta-microcontroller](https://github.com/schnitzeltony/meta-microcontroller).

---

EDIT: The following are exact reproduction steps that can be run on a machine which can Bitbake Poky (Zeus).

```
$ git clone -b zeus git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
$ cd poky
$ git clone -b zeus https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded.git
$ git clone -b zeus https://github.com/schnitzeltony/meta-microcontroller.git
$ sed -i 's/BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"/BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"/' meta-microcontroller/recipes-avr/avr-binutils/avr-binutils_2.34.bb
$ sed -i 's/BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"/BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"/' meta-microcontroller/recipes-avr/avr-gcc/avr-gcc_8.4.0.bb
$ source oe-init-build-env
$ echo 'BBMASK += "meta-microcontroller/recipes-eda/opencascade/opencascade.bb"' >> conf/local.conf
$ echo 'BBMASK += "meta-microcontroller/recipes-graphics/vtk/vtk.bb"' >> conf/local.conf
$ bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-openembedded/meta-*
$ bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-microcontroller
$ bitbake nativesdk-avr-gcc
```

---

EDIT: [Here](https://pastebin.com/Yk4ubmkd) are the generated compile tasks. I had to use pastebin since the line count is large.

Comment: I have seen many people asking questions related to Yocto, but fails to provide their `local.conf` file contents which becomes a bit difficult to reproduce the issue asked in the Question.

Comment: @GauravPathak, I have minimal configuration in my `local.conf`. This issue is easily reproducible by following the Yocto getting started and adding the files above. To make it easier I added a command list to reproduce the issue exactly.

Comment: You need to override the Optimization flag `DEBUG_PREFIX_MAP` defined in `poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf` via `conf/local.conf`. In your `local.conf` add DEBUG_PREFIX_MAP = "-fdebug-prefix-map=${WORKDIR}=/usr/src/debug/${PN}/${EXTENDPE}${PV}-${PR} \
                     -fdebug-prefix-map=${STAGING_DIR_HOST}= \
                     -fdebug-prefix-map=${STAGING_DIR_NATIVE}= \

Comment: I would be curious as to why that'd make a different since `nativesdk-avr-binutils` builds just fine. Doing as instructed reveals another error, `/bin/bash: avr-gcc: command not found`. It appears it's trying to build `nativesdk-avr-gcc` with `avr-gcc`. This doesn't make sense. Is there something that is causing this to happen in `nativesdk-avr-gcc` and not `nativesdk-avr-binutils`?

Comment: Doing some search on internet revealed that `-fmacro-prefix-map` is not supported by `gcc` version lower than `8.x`. So, either you have to configure yocto recipe to use `gcc` version greater or equal to `8.x` or remove `-fmacro-prefix-map` from  `bitbake.conf`

Comment: The `gcc` recipe I am using builds `9.2`, so this shouldn't be a problem. I do not want to modify `bitbake.conf` because it successfully builds `avr-binutils` the way it is. `avr-gcc` _should_ be no different. The `CC` set in both `run.do_compile` for `nativesdk-avr-gcc` and `nativesdk-avr-binutils`, are identical and both point to `gcc 9.2.0`. I have added the generated compile scripts to the original question.